# libDolphinDBAPI.so: undefined reference to `RSA_public_decrypt'

Tags: go, dolphindb

I used GO API of dolphindb, but there are two errors: libssl.so.10, needed by src/libwrapper.so, not found and libDolphinDBAPI.so: undefined reference to `RSA_public_decrypt'. How to resolve such problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 libssl.so.10

sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 libcrypto.so.10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.